# Google Gmail API OAuth 2.0 Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-api, gmail-api, http-status-code-400

I am trying to connect to Google's Gmail API to fetch gmail data and interact with the service through jupyter notebook and Python using Visual Studio Code. I ran Google's [quickstart.py](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python), but I keep on running into this error:
[image]

> Authorization Error
>
> Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
>
> You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's
> OAuth 2.0 policy.; If you're the app developer, register the redirect
> URI in the Google Cloud Console.

It gives me an URI each time, so I keep on adding the URI to the OAuth 2.0 but this error never seems to stop. I'm not sure what to put in here for the systems I am using (VS Code, Jupyter, and Python). I don't have an app running. I just want to do data science project with this data.

[image]

I spent many hours online trying to figure this out but none to avail... Please help me connect to Gmail! Again, I just want to download email data from Gmail and create labels to sort emails through Python.
Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Try using the OAuth2.0 playground: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground would help you narrow down this issue.

Comment: If you're following the referenced quickstart, you want a desktop application, not a web application. So, when you create the credentials for your application, you have to choose `Desktop app` instead of `Web application`. This way, you won't need to add JS origin nor redirect URI.

Comment: Hi, did my comment solve you issue? In that case, I'd consider posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following to the redirect URIs section:

- `http://localhost`
- `http://127.0.0.1`